# Cython and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2015, cython

I am trying to build python-openzwave (https://github.com/OpenZWave/python-openzwave) on Windows 2015. Unfortunatly I am not being able to build it

Here's what I have done so far:
Installed VCForPython27
Installed cython using "pip install cython"

Now when I do python setup-lib.py build, it throws the following error:
src-lib/libopenzwave/libopenzwave.cpp(356) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory

Also I have this on my setup-lib.py:

```
if os_name == 'win32' or os_name=='nt':
    ext_modules = [Extension("libopenzwave",
                         sources=["src-lib/libopenzwave/libopenzwave.cpp"],
                         libraries=['setupapi', 'stdc++'],
                         language="c++",
                         extra_objects=['openzwave/libopenzwave.a'],
                         include_dirs=['openzwave/cpp/src', 'openzwave/cpp/src/value_classes', 'openzwave/cpp/src/platform', 'openzwave/cpp/build/windows', "src-lib/libopenzwave"]
)]
```

I struggled a lot and found a lot of workaround but none has worked.

Does anyone knows how to go around this problem?

EDIT:

Here goes some more data to help anyone who is willing to help me:

```
running build
running build_ext
building 'libopenzwave' extension
C:\Users\Diogo Alves\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Iopenzwave/cpp/src -Iopenzwave/cpp/src/value_classes -Iopenzwave/cpp/src/platform -Iopenzwave/cpp/build/windows -Isrc-lib/libopenzwave "-IC:/Users/Diogo Alves/AppData/Local/Programs/Common/Microsoft/Visual C++ for Python/9.0/VC/include" -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tpsrc-lib/libopenzwave/libopenzwave.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src-lib/libopenzwave/libopenzwave.obj libopenzwave.cpp

C:/Users/Diogo Alves/AppData/Local/Programs/Common/Microsoft/Visual C++ for Python/9.0/VC/include\xlocale(342) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc src-lib/libopenzwave/libopenzwave.cpp(356) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory
```

Comment: The file *does* exist in the `VC/include` directory. You have to check where the build script is actually looking.

Comment: I added a little bit more details.

I don't know where to check this, it's the first time I am trying to use cython  and python on visual studio.... Can you give me any hints or something?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know python, or the lib. However, `stdc++` is used by the clang compiler and not by Visual Studio. Perhaps this is not the right config?

Comment: Ok I changed that to msvc still I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

The stdint.h file is only available with vs2010 (and posterior versions) and not with vs2008. Use this [stdint.h](http://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/stdint.h) and paste it in a folder in the PATH environment.